# Azure SQL Server User Provisioning

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-synapse

When provisioning a new Azure Active Directory user's access to an Azure SQL Data Warehouse or Database does the user need to be added to the **master** database in the Azure SQL Server?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities) documentation only talks about adding the Azure Active directory user to the specific warehouse database and associating them with a role within that database. I have however found that unless the user is added also added to the **master** database then they cannot sign on via SSMS.

Here is what I am doing:

```
CREATE USER [joe@domain.com]
from external provider
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'joe@domain.com'

--toggle to master
CREATE USER [joe@domain.com]
from external provider
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
```

Does the user always need to be added to master? Is there a better way to configure security so that I do not always have to add the user to master? Am I totally missing something here?

Comment: Did you try specify the database when you connect to the database with SSMS?

Comment: @LeonYue I am assuming you mean by going to options and typing the name; is this how it is supposed to work? If the user is in the _master_ database then they do not have to do this and can see all of the databases hosted the Azure SQL Server. I know in the traditional on-premise SQL Server it was generally bad practice to do anything with the _master_ database